# How can I import my passwords to Chromium from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, chromium

I have Chromium installed via Software Center. I've looked all solutions and all point out the method seen below:

[image: import bookmarks and settings menu entry]

However, it only has "Bookmarks HTML File".

[image: bookmarks html file]

I also have Firefox installed in my system, but I cannot see it. The guides on internet show this option.

So, how can I import my passwords to Chromium from Firefox?

---

## Environment

- Kubuntu 20.04.2
- Chromium 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
- Firefox 85.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best tool to sync browser passwords and bookmarks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24860/what-is-the-best-tool-to-sync-browser-passwords-and-bookmarks)